# How to handle multiple return types using Future and executer's invokeAll in Java8?

Tags: multithreading, java-8, executor, futuretask

How to handle multiple return types in future.get when invokeall is called?

```
List<Future<List<Object>>> futureListe = executor.invokeAll(Classableobjekts); //Objekts list contain two objects of different types say Class1 and CLass2.

    futureListe.stream()
      .map(future -> {
          try {
              return future.get().get(0);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
              throw new IllegalStateException(e);
          }
      }).forEach(d -> {
            if(d instanceof Class1) {   //So after response i want to check for particular response which is different for each other
                do this;
             } 
      });

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    }
```

Is it correct way to handle if future return multiple types of classes or is there better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: The list passed to `invokeAll` must contain `Callable`s, not “two objects of different types say Class1 and CLass2”. The design error starts *there*, when stuffing entirely different, apparently unrelated callables into a list. What’s the point of requiring them *all* to be completed before processing individual, unrelated results?

Comment: Invoke them seaparately? Otherwise you could let them return some common interface.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich: Kindly update answer